# How to fix from storyboard "Main", but didn't get a UITableView.' xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am very new to iOS programming.
I am running a simple app from a tutorial and when i try to run it on Simulator(iPhone 11) it gives me following error message

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UITableViewController loadView] instantiated view controller with identifier "UIViewController-BYZ-38-t0r" from storyboard "Main", but didn't get a UITableView.'`

AppDeligate

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        let viewController = ViewController()
        window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController)

        return true
    }

    // MARK: UISceneSession Lifecycle
    @available(iOS 13.0, *)
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
        // Called when a new scene session is being created.
        // Use this method to select a configuration to create the new scene with.
        return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
    }

    @available(iOS 13.0, *)
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {
        // Called when the user discards a scene session.
        // If any sessions were discarded while the application was not running, this will be called shortly after application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.
        // Use this method to release any resources that were specific to the discarded scenes, as they will not return.
    }


}
```

ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Logout", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleLogout))
    }

    @objc
    func handleLogout() {
        let loginController = LoginController()
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(loginController, animated: true)
    }
}
```

And this is how my Main.Storyboard looks like

How can I fix this please, I looked online but as I am totally new to iOS world I am unable to fix it.

Thanks
R

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Replace the view controller you see on the main storyboard with a UITableviewcontroller. Just Drag and drop the table view controller and make it as initial view controller.

Then add a UItableviewcontroller class into your project. Name the scene UITableview controller the same as the table view controller class name. And don’t forget to connect all the outlets with the view controller class. Attach the storyboard scene with the class name using the sidebar given on the right side in the Custom Class column.
[image]
￼￼

Answer (score 0):

The crash means you use a usual vc not a tableVC , you must drag this ( hit command + shift + l )

[image]

With this look

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try to fix this here:

```
inplace : class ViewController: UITableViewController {

use : class ViewController: UIViewController {
```

Comment: When I do that, and run the app, app runs on the phone but i just see a white screen

Comment: IN Storyboard embed your controller with navigationcontroller

Comment: Hi Anil, really sorry, how do I do that

Comment: In your Storyboard, you can embed a ViewController in a Navigation Controller by selecting the View Controller and then picking from the menu at the top Editor->Embed In->Navigation Controller.

Comment: hey Anil, i managed to get it sorted with UITableViewController, thank you so much for responding

Comment: Hello Anil, I tried your aproach using UIViewController and embedded navigation controller but still it is the same, i cannot see the logout button